# Refactoring enum block c++

Tags: c++, enums, refactoring, global

I'm currently trying to break a large "all-in-one-file" program into separate modules in order to make it easier to work with. My problem is that the original (all in one file) version of the program used an enum declaration. I want to continue to use this declaration in the new version of the program that is split into multiple classes, but I'm not sure the best way to do it.

The easiest solution that came to mind was to put the enum block in a header file and to try and use it as a global variable (I know global variables are generally bad, is this an appropriate use?) However, that generated a bunch of "error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int".

I realize this is similar to questions that have been asked before. However, all the answers I've been able to find are a bit too technical or not quite what I'm looking for.

My Global.h file and the file where the errors are occurring are included below.

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_
#define GLOBAL_H_
#include <SDL.h>
#include "LTexture.h"
#include "LButton.h"


enum LButtonSprite
{
    BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_OUT = 0,
    BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_OVER_MOTION = 1,
    BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_DOWN = 2,
    BUTTON_SPRITE_TOTAL = 2
};
.
.
#endif GLOBAL_H_
```

...

```
#ifndef LBUTTON_H
#define LBUTTON_H
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Global.h"

class LButton
{
public:
    //Initializes internal variables
    LButton();

    //Sets top left position
    void setPosition(int x, int y);

    //Handles mouse event
    void handleEvent(SDL_Event* e);

    //Shows button sprite
    void render();

    LButtonSprite getCurrSprite();//Problem is here

private:
    //Button Position
    SDL_Point mPosition;

    //Button Sprite
    LButtonSprite mCurrentSprite;//And here

};
#endif
```

Firstly, what is causing this error? Secondly, can anyone suggest a better way implement what I'm trying to do?

My suspicion is that the compiler is confusing LButtonSprite for a variable. This is based on the colour coding provided by VS (return types are blue, but LButtonSprite is light blue). As can be seen in LButton.h (included below) LButtonSprite should be read as a return type and not as a variable.

Thanks!

Comment: `LButtonSprite` is a type not a variable and cannot be declared `extern`.

Answer (score 1):

Without the 'extern' keyword what you've posted is fine.

To avoid naming collisions you could put the enum in a namespace or a class.

Also, if LButton is the only class that uses this enum it could just as well be defined within the class definition of LButton itself.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense. Why are you declaring it `extern` when you're defining it? `extern` is used for declarations that are defined *elsewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

`Global.h` and `LButton.h` each `#include` the other. This means the compiler sees the `LButton` class before it can see the `LButtonSprite` enum, and that's why you are seeing an error message. Either remove the

```
#include "LButton.h"
```

from `Global.h` or at least put it below the `enum` declaration.